Error in Firebase Auth (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.) in Nuxt 3, when getting config from .env in nuxt.config.ts
Github repo: https://github.com/aidanandrews22/daps_simulation
In nuxt.config.ts I'm using runtimeConfig.public.firebase for getting all of the config info from .env file which is located in frontend folder (github repo) and using useRuntimeConfig() to access that data in firebase-manual.ts file. With Firestore and Storage it works completely fine. But with Authentication it works only when HARDCODING the config object in the runtimeConfig.public.firebase in nuxt config file. It is weird because whenever I console.log in nuxt config file and in firebase-manual.ts all of the config info is showing in console, which means that Firestore and Storage work in both scenarios (while the config is hardcoded or the config is imported from .env file). But authentication works only when the config info in nuxt file is hardcoded. How to fix it?
-------nuxt.config.ts-------
(this is how I want this to be, this works with Firestore and Storage but not Authentication)
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') })

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'
import * as path from 'path'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

console.log('Firebase config in nuxt.config.ts:', {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  // ... other config values
})

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&callback=initMap`,
        async: true,
        defer: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  env: {
    GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  },
  modules: ['@unocss/nuxt'],
  css: ['./assets/css/main.css'],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          'postcss-import': {},
          'unocss/postcss': {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
      // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE .ENV CONFIG FILES
      firebase: {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: ['~/plugins/firebase-manual.ts'],
})


-----nuxt.config.ts-----
(this is the hardcoded one, and it works with Firestore, Storage and Authentication, but this version is not safe, it shouldn't be hardcoded)
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') })

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'
import * as path from 'path'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

console.log('Firebase config in nuxt.config.ts:', {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  // ... other config values
})

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&callback=initMap`,
        async: true,
        defer: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  env: {
    GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  },
  modules: ['@unocss/nuxt'],
  css: ['./assets/css/main.css'],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          'postcss-import': {},
          'unocss/postcss': {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
      // NOW IT'S HARDCODED
      firebase: {
        apiKey: '...',
        authDomain: '...',
        projectId: '...',
        storageBucket: '...',
        messagingSenderId: '...',
        appId: '...',
        measurementId: '...',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: ['~/plugins/firebase-manual.ts'],
})


-------firebase-manual.ts-------
import { getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  console.log(config.public.firebase.apiKey)

  const apps = getApps()
  const firebaseApp = apps.length === 0 ? initializeApp(config.public.firebase) : apps[0]
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
  const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
  const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp)

  nuxtApp.provide('firebase', { firebaseApp, auth, firestore, storage })
})


The issue you're facing with Firebase Authentication not working when using environment variables from the .env file in your Nuxt configuration.
You can add console log first to check if the configs are loading in:
console.log('Firebase config in nuxt.config.ts:', {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
});

Or try using useRuntimeConfig plugin
const config = useRuntimeConfig().public.firebase;

Or check firebase Initialization
const firebaseApp = apps.length === 0 ? initializeApp(config) : apps[0];

the initializeApp should be called.
And also make sure you put correct .env value names its a comman mistake

They are in my console when I debug them, it works.
But the when I sign up it gives me that error
